# Difference between runOnUiThread() method and @UiThreadTest annotation

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

As the title, can anyone explain the difference between the runOnUiThread() method and the @UiThreadTest annotation? I've been reading through the Android testing tutorial (http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html) which uses both. It states:

> Code in a test application that interacts with a View of the application under test must run in the main application's thread, also known as the UI thread. To do this, you use the Activity.runOnUiThread() method

and:

> The @UiThreadTest annotation tells Android to build this method so that it runs on the UI thread. This allows the method to change the state of the spinner widget in the application under test.

For the runOnUi() method, the code in question is

```
public void testASpinnerUI()
{
    mActivity.runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    mSpinner.requestFocus();
                    mSpinner.setSelection(INITIAL_POSITION);
                }// end of run
            } // end of runnable
        ); //end of runOnUiThread

    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER);
    for (int i = 0; i < TEST_POSITION; i++)
    {
        this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN);
    }
    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER);

    mPos = mSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    mSelection = (String) mSpinner.getItemAtPosition(mPos);

    TextView resultView = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(com.android.example.spinner.R.id.SpinnerResult);

    String resultText = (String) resultView.getText();
    assertEquals(resultText, mSelection);
}
```

and for the @UiThreadTest annotation:

```
@UiThreadTest
public void testStatePause()
{
    Instrumentation mInstr = this.getInstrumentation();
    mActivity.setSpinnerPosition(TEST_STATE_PAUSE_POSITION);
    mActivity.setSpinnerSelection(TEST_STATE_PAUSE_SELECTION);

    mInstr.callActivityOnPause(mActivity);

    mActivity.setSpinnerPosition(0);
    mActivity.setSpinnerSelection("");

    mInstr.callActivityOnResume(mActivity);

    int currentPosition = mActivity.getSpinnerPosition();
    String currentSelection = mActivity.getSpinnerSelection();

    assertEquals(TEST_STATE_PAUSE_POSITION, currentPosition);
    assertEquals(TEST_STATE_PAUSE_SELECTION, currentSelection);     
}
```

They appear to be interchangeable, in the sense that I can remove the annotation from the annotated test and include its contents in a runOnUiThread() method and it passes. Similarly, I can remove the runOnUiThread() method from the other test and add the @UiThreadTest annotation and it passes.

So what's the difference?

Additionally, the tutorial includes another test:

```
public void testStateDestroy()
{
    mActivity.setSpinnerPosition(TEST_STATE_DESTROY_POSITION);
    mActivity.setSpinnerSelection(TEST_STATE_DESTROY_SELECTION);

    mActivity.finish();
    mActivity = getActivity();

    int currentPosition = mActivity.getSpinnerPosition();
    String currentSelection = mActivity.getSpinnerSelection();

    assertEquals(TEST_STATE_DESTROY_POSITION, currentPosition);
    assertEquals(TEST_STATE_DESTROY_SELECTION, currentSelection);
}
```

This test also interacts with the activity but requires neither the @UiThreadTest annotation or a runOnUiThread() method. Why is this?

Comment: That third test definitely looks not thread-safe.

Comment: it doesn't fail though. The other tests do without the runOnUi method or @UiThreadTest annotation

Comment: Sorry, after re-reading the test, no, it's not a race. Both setting and reading happen from the test thread (assuming the UI thread doesn't touch those values). So, the `set/get` pairs are not race conditions. The `finish()` call might be, since we're not waiting for it but that makes the test invalid, not failing (i.e., it's not testing the right thing, though the result might still be `success`).

Comment: When I use `@UiThreadTest` and not `@Test`, Android Studio makes the name of the test gray, as if nobody calls it. Gotta add the `@Test` these days!

Answer (score 10):

The difference is in semantics and side effects.

First, the presence of `@UiThreadTest` causes the activity to be created if it hasn't been already [by calling `getActivity()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java#187).

Then, in [InstrumentatinTestCase](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.java#186), it uses `getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync()` to run the full test.

The difference between [`getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/app/Instrumentation.java#343) and [`Activity.runOnUiThread()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/app/Activity.java#4669) is that the former waits for the call to finish (needed when running a full test or, you know, calling things inside a test) while the latter doesn't.

Other than that, they post to different `Handler`s (`runOnMainSync` uses the one from `ActivityThread`, while the `Activity` instance has its own) but that's irrelevant, since they're getting scheduled on the same `MessageQueue`.

Comment: Thanks. So when would you use one over the other? In the tutorial (link added to question) what made them choose?

Comment: Hmmm... the testASpinnerUI test in which I replaced runOnUi with @UiThreadTest is failing now. I'm certain it passed earlier... Some timing issue perhaps

Comment: The runOnUi version of testASpinnerUI has a race condition  in it. The runOn call just schedules the call, it doesn't wait for it to be executed. You need to use `runOnMainSync` there. The @UiThreadTest version of testASpinnerUi should work just fine (I think; `sendKeys` should be safe but I'm not 100% sure, even though the doc says it's okay). Generally, you shouldn't use straight `runOnUiThread` since that will not wait for the runnable to be executed,you need `runOnMainSync` instead. That said, I just use [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/). It's hacky (sleeps a lot) but works.

Comment: Also, Google are sitting on an internal library of theirs, called Espresso, which uses fest assertions and handles sync for you. They still haven't released it, though, but do keep an eye out.

Comment: I tried to verify what you said about the difference between runOnUi and runOnMainSync by adding a Thread.sleep(10000) in the runnable. In both cases the test passed as the runnable code executed before the rest of the test. So it seems in both cases the runnable was allowed to complete. This is very confusing - am I misubnderstanding something?